# python Invalid syntax Error : print

Tags: python

I try to write my first python program. But the print function is very special. I tried to write :

```
print ("success!")
```

very normal. but IDLE remind me that the code is wrong and "print" has been red. What should I do?

Comment: Are you using python3 or python2?

Comment: That's valid syntax for both Python 2 & 3

Comment: Can you share your actual code, and the full Traceback (error message)? (Please [edit] these into your question, rather than add a comment)

Comment: Also, this might just by IDLE's syntax highlighting where keywords are coloured (they are orange on my screen). Did you actually get any error?

Comment: have you tried reinstalling python?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just seeing IDLE's syntax-highlighting feature. Keywords (and function names, variables etc.) are given different colours, in order to make the code easier to read (and spot errors like missing brackets etc.):

If you are seeing the same as this:

[image]

Then, you have nothing to worry about

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this isn't just IDLE's syntax highlighting (hard to tell without the code in question)...

The reason for this odd behaviour has to do with a major change that was made in Python 3.  In Python 2, `print` is a keyword. In Python 3, `print` is a function.

This has a number of implications:

1. In Python3, `print` requires parentheses
2. In Python2, `print` does not require parentheses by default
3. In Python2, `print` cannot be overridden by default (you cannot change what `print` does)
4. In Python3, `print` can be shadowed in a module, providing different behaviour for one application or another.

Now, what this means is that the syntax by default is different, but the good news is you can get the same syntax on both by putting as the first line in your module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

As a side note, this is a good idea since it ensures the same code will run on Python 2.7 and 3.  So I add to all my Python modules these days:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
```

(adding division there is good practice because of the way the division operator changed.)

Comment: `print ("success!")` will work in both Python 2 & 3 though.

Comment: @SiHa He is referring python2 when `print` is not a function. He is not talking about specific version like 2.7 or lower.

Comment: @SkrewEverything I realise that (hence I didn't downvote the answer). It doesn't answer the fact that the code the OP wrote isn't a Syntax error in *either* version, however. At the end of the day, the problem here is lack of in formation from the OP, we're all guessing. The question should really be closed as off-topic - no MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be anywhere in the line that `print` appears in check for example if you have the right indention